# Java Regex for HTML status code when checking entire multiline HTML header

Tags: java, regex, match, multiline

I want to verify HTTP response status code - the syntax is `HTML/1.1 200 ...` The string passed is multiline, containing line breaks. My preliminary regex is `^(HTTP|http)/(1|2)\\.\\d \\d{3}.+$`. Works well when I pass only one line, without line breaks and the rest rows. What is wrong with this regex? Here is sample code:

```
System.out.println(
        "HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\n"
        + "Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 03:04:38 GMT\n"
        + "Content-Type: video/mp4\n"
        + "Date: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 21:44:08 GMT\n"
        + "Expires: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 21:44:08 GMT\n"
        + "Cache-Control: private, max-age=21294\n"
        + "Content-Range: bytes 0-17016614/17016615\n"
        + "Accept-Ranges: bytes\n"
        + "Content-Length: 17016615\n"
        + "Connection: keep-alive".matches("^(HTTP|http)/(1|2)\\.\\d \\d{3}.+$"));
```

**EDIT:**

I think it is more effective to substring only the first line and then check if it match. And regex is more simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` may not match line breaks. Try using `(.|\\s)+` instead to also match whitespace characters:

```
^(HTTP|http)/(1|2)\\.\\d \\d{3}(.|\\s)+$
```

Based on your edited question, the problem is that the concatenated strings should be placed in parentheses, otherwise the `matches` method is called against the last string part:

```
System.out.println(
      ("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content\n"
      + "Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 03:04:38 GMT\n"
      + "Content-Type: video/mp4\n"
      + "Date: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 21:44:08 GMT\n"
      + "Expires: Sat, 14 Mar 2015 21:44:08 GMT\n"
      + "Cache-Control: private, max-age=21294\n"
      + "Content-Range: bytes 0-17016614/17016615\n"
      + "Accept-Ranges: bytes\n"
      + "Content-Length: 17016615\n"
      + "Connection: keep-alive").matches("^(HTTP|http)/(1|2)\\.\\d \\d{3}(.|\\s)+$"));
```

Comment: Indeed, it was very interesting to know, that parentheses here make a difference - never noticed that.. Regex now working thanks to `(.|\\s)`. Super, thanks! :)